# Use a method from other classes w/o inheritance

Tags: python, django, inheritance

This question is about *Python* inheritance but is explained with a Django example, this should't hurt though.

I have this Django model, with `Page` and `RichText` models as well:

```
class Gallery(Page, RichText):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # lot of code to unzip, check and create image instances.
        return "something"
```

I'm only interested in using the `save` method in another class.

A solution could be:

```
class MyGallery(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # here goes the code duplicated from Gallery, the same.
        return "something"
```

I'd like to avoid the code duplication and also I'm not interested in inheriting members from `Page` and `RichText` (so I don't want to do `class MyGallery(Gallery):`. If it would be legal I'd write something like this:

```
class MyGallery(models.Model):
    # custom fields specific for MyGallery
    # name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    # etc

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return Gallery.save(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

But it won't work because the `save()` in `Gallery` expects an instance of `Gallery`, not `MyGallery`.

Any way to "detach" the `save()` method from `Gallery` and use it in `MyGallery` as it were defined there?

**EDIT:**

I forgot to say that `Gallery` is given and can't be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the [`__func__` attribute of the `save` method](http://docs.python.org/dev/reference/datamodel.html#index-35):

```
class Gallery(object):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self, args, kwargs

class MyGallery(object):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return Gallery.save.__func__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    # or 
    # save = Gallery.save.__func__

mg = MyGallery()
print mg.save('arg', kwarg='kwarg')
# (<__main__.MyGallery object at 0x04DAD070>, ('arg',), {'kwarg': 'kwarg'})
```

but you're better off refactoring if possible:

```
class SaveMixin(object):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self, args, kwargs

class Gallery(SaveMixin, object):
    pass

class MyGallery(SaveMixin, object):
    pass
```

or

```
def gallery_save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return self, args, kwargs

class Gallery(object):
    save = gallery_save

class MyGallery(object):
    save = gallery_save
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are against inheritance, particularly with regard to methods. I regularly create a `MixIn` class that is inherited by all of my Django `models.Model`, and it contains all manner of useful methods for URL creation, dumps, etc., etc. I do make the methods defensive in that they use `hasattr()` to make sure they apply to a particular class, but doing this is a real time saver.

Comment: I'm not against inheritance in general, but in this case I am. If `MyGallery` would inherit from `Gallery`, the subclass would have methods I will never use, so it seems a nonsense to me to have something you don't use but require memory, too. Then, for how Django works, the inherited classes would also contribute in terms of new database fields (useless in my scenario).

Comment: Finally, mixins don't fit well because I cannot change the `Gallery` class.

Comment: @Guandalino: I accept that this is not how you want to do it, but I don't believe that in Python methods inherited from other classes take any more room than a simple pointer from the child class to the parent class. As for the DB fields, I am in total agreement with you. I've tried to do that a couple of times and it was a) awkward, b) unintuitive. Good Luck.

Comment: at the end of the story I think you are right for everything. But still the mixin solution doesn't apply in my case. Thanks for sharing your thoughts.